# libvlc programmatically play microphone capture

Tags: directshow, libvlc

I'm trying to programmatically play microphone capture(but can be any audio-in device).
OS: Windows, VLC capture mode: DirectShow. Using GUI like in the image everything is great:

[image]

I'm doing something like:

```
libvlc_vlm_add_broadcast(vlc_inst, "mybroadcast", "dshow:// :dshow-vdev=none :dshow-adev=VIA HD Audio Input  :live-caching=300", "", 0, NULL, TRUE, 0);

libvlc_vlm_play_media(vlc_inst, "mybroadcast");
```

but doesn't work. How shall I do it?

Comment: I am not familiar with libvlc, but this looks suspicious: `:dshow-adev=VIA HD Audio Input`. Often when there are spaces in a parameter, it needs quotes around it.

Comment: I think you need another set of quotes around the name of the device. That worked for me.